# What's the C# equivalent of the following VB.NET code?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have this code written in VB.NET that I need to convert to C# but I'm running in some problems.

This is the code in VB:

```
For Each c in Me.Controls
    If TypeOf (c) Is PictureBox Then
        CType(c,PictureBox).Image = icon;
        AddHandler c.Click, AddressOf PictureBox10_Click
    End If
```

So basically I'm trying to make it check for PictureBoxes and give them an icon and to make those PictureBoxes have the same function that PictureBox10 Click event has.

Here is the code I've written in C#:

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls)
{
    if (c.GetType() == typeof(System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox))
    {
        ((PictureBox)c).Image = Properties.Resorces.available;
        c.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.pictureBox10_Click);
    }
}
```

It works till the Image part but I can't get the `EventHandler` working.

Also here is what the PictureBox10 Click Event does:

```
private void pictureBox10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    if (pictureBox10.Image == Properties.Resorces.available)
        pictureBox10.Image = Properties.Resorces.selected;
    else if (pictureBox10.Image == Properties.Resorces.selected)
        pictureBox10.Image = Properties.Resorces.available;
}
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: You wrote this.PictureBox10_Click and the name is **p**ictureBox10_Click

Comment: `c.Click += pictureBox10_Click;`

Comment: Note that assigning resources that way will result in your app leaking (in VB as well).  Resources is not a collection, but a factory which creates *new* images etc.  As such they must be disposed of.  Besides you do not need a *new* image each time.  At the start of the app load those images into an array and assign from there.  It also means that `if (pictureBox10.Image == Properties.Resorces.available)` will never work because `Properties.Resorces.available` creates a new one each time  - use a flag to track the image shown

Comment: That's a typo I made while writing it here. It's correct on the code. What it does tho is that when I click on any other pictureBox it changes pictureBox10 icon but when I click pictureBox10 it does nothing.

Comment: What does the debugger tell you when you step through the code?

Comment: Your 'if' statement just needs to be:  if (c is PictureBox)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code to select a picturebox can be simplified using the `System.Linq` extension method, `OfType`, which selects only the controls specified in the `OfType` argument, and returns them as that type. Also, we can assign a common event hanlder to all these controls:

```
foreach (PictureBox pb in Controls.OfType<PictureBox>())
{
    pb.Image = Properties.Resorces.available;
    pb.Click += PictureBox_Click;  // Defined below
}
```

Then in the event handler, we cast `sender` to a `PictureBox` so that we have a strongly-typed object, which allows us to then set the `Image` property:

```
private void PictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var thisPictureBox = sender as PictureBox;

    // May not be necessary, but it's a good practice to ensure that 'sender' was actually
    // a PictureBox and not some other object by checking if 'thisPictureBox' is 'null'
    if (thisPictureBox == null) return;

    if (thisPictureBox.Image == Properties.Resorces.available)
    {
        thisPictureBox.Image = Properties.Resorces.selected;
    {
    else if (thisPictureBox.Image == Properties.Resorces.selected)
    {
        thisPictureBox.Image = Properties.Resorces.available;
    }
}
```